# How to perform cross-domain SAML-based authentication/trust

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cross-domain, wif, saml

I have a product which consists of internal ASP.NET/MVC web sites all using WIF to enable SSO through a custom STS/IdP service. We now have a new partner site hosted outside our network on another domain and would like to enable SSO for users as they navigate between the sites. The new site uses different technologies (e.g. python) but we assume we can create a trust relationship using SAML standards as the protocol.

With SAML as the underlying protocol we assume this can be achieved but we cannot find any guidance on patterns for implementation, best practice guidance, etc... Can some recommend some resources on how to establish this type of cross-domain trust?

Note: While other options like OAuth could address this, we would prefer to stick with a SAML-based solution

Answer (score 1):

Does your custom STS/IdP service support SAML?

On the python side, they will need a SAML stack. There's a number around - refer [Introduction to OneLogin's SAML Toolkits](https://onelogin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201175714-Introduction-to-OneLogin-s-SAML-Toolkits) e.g. There's a good diagram there as well that shows the login flow.

Then you need to get the python SAML metadata and give them your custom STS/IdP SAML metadata.

Import on both sides, configure whatever assertions you need and you should be good to go.

You'll also need to sort out the signing certificates that go into the metadata.

Example of process using simpleSAMLPHP - [Configuring the SP](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp)

Answer (score 0):

Following provides excellent example of SAML implementation:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56640/Performing-a-SAML-Post-with-C

We used it in our project and it worked fine.